# How should I start writing the code in the src/test/file.me if using node js and yarn to click on a button?

Tags: javascript, java, html, reactjs, eclipse

I have the below code in src/components/Introduction.jsx file which I have not created and want to work further on it.

```
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import { Img } from 'react-image';
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../logo.png';

const paperStyle = {
  padding: 20,
  height: 6000,
  margin: 20,
  alignItems: 'center',
  textAlign: 'center',
  backgroundColor: '#ced7e5',
};

const Logo = () => <Img src={logo} />;

const Introduction = props => (
  <section id="home">
    <Paper style={paperStyle} zDepth={3}>
      <Logo />
      <h1 className="title">Welcome</h1>
      <p className="intro">
        Using the programming language of your choice we want you to create a selenium framework
        in .src/test/e2e.Use selenium to click the button below to continue with the test.
      </p>
      <RaisedButton data-test-id="render-challenge" label="Render the Challenge" primary onClick={props.showChallenge} />
      <p>You might have noticed that clicking that button starts a really, really long scroll. </p>
      <p>I wonder how you are going to handle that? </p>
      <span style={{ fontSize: 60 }} role="img" aria-label="down-emoj" >â¬‡ï¸�</span>
    </Paper>
  </section>
);

export default Introduction;
```

I want to click on **RENDER THE CHALLENGE** button. I think that there is already a method to click on **RENDER THE CHALLENGE** button in this Introduction.jsx file. My question is do I need to write something in the src/test/e2e/implement.me the file? And if yes, then what? Or is it that the props have just defined the objects on the page layout? and the actual clicking should be done in the src/test/e2e/implement.me file?
[image]
Button image

I have the below configuration:

[image]

and I'm executing the script using **yarn start**. So my question is what code should I add in implement.me file for clicking the button. Or do I need to configure Selenium Webdriver in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Find the element by this Xpath expression:

//*[contains(text(),'RENDER THE CHALLENGE')]

```
WebElement we = browser.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
we.click();
```

Comment: ```driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));```

Comment: Better by id, or By.cssSelector, the use of By.xpath is expensive.

Comment: Please read my description and the heading again, I have updated it. Also, my concern is how should I start writing code in implement.me file? Clicking on the button is just an example. The application launches when I use ``yarn start ``in command prompt. There I find the page having RENDER THE CHALLENGE button. Let me know if you are understanding what I'm trying to say.